# A question on the Bombieri-Lang conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety of general type, defined over a number field $K$. Then the Bombieri-Lang conjecture asserts that the set of rational points $X(K)$ (or $X(L)$ for any finite extension $L/K$) is not Zariski-dense in $X$.

As far as I know, this is only known in the case of a curve (Faltings' theorem) or when $X$ is a subvariety of an abelian variety. Further, to my knowledge all proofs of these results are rather indirect, getting at the relevant finiteness results in somewhat roundabout ways.

If Bombieri-Lang holds, then it must be true that there exists for each variety $X$ of general type defined over $K$ and finite extension $L/K$ an algebraic set $\mathcal{X}_L$ which contains $X(L)$, but does not contain $X$ as a variety.

My question concerns what I call $\mathcal{X}_L$ above: has there been any attempt to construct the (closed) algebraic set $\mathcal{X}_L$? With what I said above $\mathcal{X}_L$ is not necessarily unique of course. If one can construct such a $\mathcal{X}_L$ then one can prove, rather directly, that Bombier-Lang holds, so clearly constructing such a thing is a difficult problem. Are there any conjectural frameworks that predict what such things look like? Importantly, $\mathcal{X}_L$ necessarily depends on both $X$ as an algebraic variety and the number field $L$.

Comment: (1) It's also known for proper varieties with a finite map to the moduli stack of abelian varieties (also Faltings' theorem). I believe that, using the minimal compactification, you can make examples of these that aren't curves.  (2) There are attempts to construct a closed algebraic set that contains all but finitely many of the rational points. This you can do independently of $L$. (3) If you don't allow finite error, I don't think there will be any construction of this type, simply because rational points appear "at random".

Comment: (4) What exists are things like conjectures bounding the heights of rational points (for curves, an effective form of ABC would suffice), which give you a computational procedure to produce a list of rational points which conjecturally includes all of them (by exhaustively searching for points of small height) but which I wouldn't think of as  a construction of $\mathcal X_L$.

Comment: @WillSawin regarding your point 2), where can I find such attempts? That looks very interesting!

Comment: This is "Lang's geometric conjecture": Let $X$ be a smooth projective
variety of general type. There is a Zariski closed proper subset $S(X) \subset X$,
whose irreducible components are not of general type, and such that every
subset $T \subset X$ not of general type is contained in $S(X)$.

Comment: I don't know about *attempts*, but there is a stronger version of the Bombieri–Lang conjecture that predicts that (1) the smallest closed subscheme $Z \subseteq X$ containing all images of morphisms from abelian varieties to $X$ is a *strict* closed subset $Z \subsetneq X$ and (2) for any field extension $K \subseteq L$, there are only finitely many $L$-points of $X$ not contained in $Z$. The first statement is purely geometric, and is called the Green–Griffiths–Lang conjecture. (I might have gotten the statements slightly wrong as I usually only think about surfaces.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn GGL is an analytic conjecture. It conjectures that, for a proj variety of general type, the entire curves $\mathbb{C}\to X^{an}$ land in some proper closed subset.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao What you want to look for is the "exceptional locus" and the notion of "pseudo-hyperbolicity". See for example Lang's paper: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-14/issue-2/Hyperbolic-and-Diophantine-analysis/bams/1183553166.full

Comment: The "exceptional locus" comes in many different flavours (algebraic, geometric, analytic, arithmetic...). You are thinking about the arithmetic one. It is defined by taking the union over all positive-dimensional components of the closure of $X(L)$ in $X$ as $L$ ranges over all finite (or finitely generated) extentions of your base (number) field $K$.

Comment: The "strongest" version of Lang's conjectures is that all these exceptional loci are equal; see Section 12 of this survey https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11981 .

Comment: This very strong version says in particular that, if you define $\Delta\subset X$ to be the closure over all images of rational maps $A \dashrightarrow X$ with $A$ ranging over all abelian varieties (over $\overline{k}$), then this $\Delta$ should be THE exceptional locus. In the survey above this is called the "groupless" exceptional locus, but sometimes it is also called the "algebraic" exceptional locus. It obviously contains all rational curves, elliptic curves, and abelian varieties, but it also contains  all big opens of abelian varieties (e.g., $A-\{0\}$) contained in $X$.

Comment: So, all in all, in any specific example where you are interested in what such an exceptional locus might really look like, you are probably best off trying to find all images of elliptic curves (this includes all rational curves) first. If you can do that, then you have pretty much found the obvious candidate for the arithmetic/geometric/analytic exceptional locus.